# Time dialation as observed on Earth

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, time-dilation, observers

Probably a silly question but, I wanted to know if someone has taken a wind up clock into space and observed time dialation?

If all our observations are by electronic methods, we dont know if electrics/electronics are influenced by earths magnetic properties, or do we?

Comment: On the contrary we know *how* (and how much) electronics are affected by magnetic fields. And there would be no point in using a wind-up clock, because the precision of mechanical chronometers is insufficient to manage the measurement. This is a place where understanding the mathematical scale of the effect is very important.

Answer (score 1):

The Einstein theory of relativity did theorize time-dilation and accelerated frames in 1907. However, in 1979 Joseph Hafele and Richard Keating did experiments in a commercial jet contrasting the stationary clock with the other in different location, regarding that one quantum field theory and shared there results with the public, they found that they had two elapsed times, thus time dilation does well exist and it is the same for an observer from space and on earth there study also proved that time dilation has a simultaneous effect in both spacecraft and on earth. Thanks I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Welcome Dylan. One minor point that doesn’t change your answer is that the HK experiment was done on a normal commercial jet, not a fighter.

Comment: Thank you Dale, I will edit that to clarify!

Answer (score 0):

Even if your assumption about electronic devices were correct, einsteins theory of relativity that is responsible for the time dilation has been proven in a number of other ways. 
Gravity lensing for example is an effect that has been observed before as well as the prediction of mercury's orbit to a higher degree of accuracy. 
So while you might suspect that the electronic clocks are susceptible to earths magnetic fields, other proof for the validity of einstein's theory provides some certainty that the observed time dilation is indeed an effect of relativity.

Comment: Please forgive me if I sound naive, but this is the exact reason I asked the question. The common is as observed from earth. Lensing is also as observed from earth. If my understanding is correct, the further we travel from earth physics says our current understanding of physics is inacurate to a point where if we travell far enough our understanding of physics is invalid, hence my question.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood something about the properties of our universe. One of the laws of relativity is that the universe is uniform and that laws apply everywhere. This homogeneity is part of the reason why relativity works